# how to grab text from dynamically created li element in angular from html to ts component

Tags: angular

Please help me with this.  Here is the code

Xpressions Total ={{response.total}}
                      clear

```
                </div>
            <div class="exResult">
              <ul>
                <li *ngFor='let item of response.data'>
                  {{item.phrase}}
               </li>
              </ul>
            </div>    
          </div>
```

how to add click event to this li element so that I can grab text and use it in my app component.

Comment: what have you tried until now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
<li *ngFor='let item of response.data' (click)="functionName(item)">
    {{item.phrase}}
</li>
```

and in your ts file write a function with "functionName" and here you can have item.phrase. You don't need reading text inside of li element.

Comment: how to add this item to array in ts file.  Thanks in advance

Comment: proResponse: any[] = [];...........I need to add item to this array.  ........Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. you can add item to array with `code`proResponse.push(newItem)`code`